# Assume $f : A \to B$ and both $X$ and $Y$ are subsets of $A.$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am having a hard time solving these two questions.

Assume $f : A \to B$ and both $X$ and $Y$ are subsets of $A.$

(a) Prove: $f(X \cup Y ) = f(X) \cup f(Y)$

(b) Give an example that shows $f(X \cap Y ) = f(X) \cap f(Y )$ may be
false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one, do a double inclusion.

Let $f(c) \in f(X\cup Y)$. Then $c \in X\cup Y$, so $c \in X$, or $c \in Y$, or both. If $c \in X$, then $f(c) \in f(X) \subset f(X) \cup f(Y).$ Similarly for $c \in Y$. Thus, $f(X\cup Y) \subset f(X) \cup f(Y)$.
On the other hand, let $f(c) \in f(X) \cup f(Y).$ Then, $c \in X$, $c \in Y$, or both. Hence, $f(c) \in f(X \cup Y),$ so $f(X) \cup f(Y) \subset f(X \cup Y)$
Hence,  $f(X) \cup f(Y) = f(X \cup Y)$.

For the second one, let $X = \{1\}, Y = \{2\}$, and define $f(1) = f(2) = 10$.

Answer (score 1):

For (a) think about what it means for an element to be a subset of the function applied to the intersection and a subset of the intersection of the function applied to X and Y.

For (b) consider a situation where X and Y have no elements in common. Can you use such a case to construct a counterexample?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

(a) If $z \in f(X \cup Y)$ then $z =f(x)$ for some $x \in X \cup Y$.

What does it mean that $x \in X \cup Y$?

Next: If $z \in f(X) \cup f(Y)$ then $x \in f(x)$ or $x \in f(y)$.

(b) Can you figure a situation when $X \cap Y =\emptyset$ but $f(X) \cap f(Y) \neq \emptyset$?